# POST request works in POSTMAN but not in my code JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, postman

I tried my post request in POSTMAN everything working fine.
When I pasted the code as Ajax or XRH from POSTMAN, I've got an error message :

```
 -  net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed) from chrome or firefox
```

I am working as localhost from home : can it be a privileges access issue and I don't have enough rights to POST as localhost ?

here is my post request :

```js
 var data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("backup_date", date);
    data.append("backed_up_device_name", device);
    
 var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "url",
  "method": "POST",
  "dataType": "jsonp",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": data
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: What is your server url path? "url" is not right.

Answer (score 0):

> The server MUST generate an **Allow** header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.

For further information, see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)

That is to say, the POST request to `url` is not acceptable by your server. Try looking at this carefully:

```
"url": "url", // what is the url? `"url":"ServerURL"`
```

Comment: url = obviously the path to the server :)
thanks for the doc i gonna read this